# Trigger chrome.browserAction.onClicked with a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to trigger the click, to which following code is listening:

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {});`

The reason is that I have a working extension, which is listening in a background-script (the addListener above) and executes some scripts on click:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'abc.js'});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'xxx.js'});
});
```

And now I want to trigger this "onClicked" from a context-menu:

```
var myContextPage = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": myTitle, "contexts":["page"],
                                     "onclick": fctContext});
```

So, I thought, that the easiest way would be to have "click" in fctContext.
Maybe there is a better way, but I don't how to solve my problem. I also tried to run "executeScript" but this isn't working neither.

Thanks in advance!

***//Update***

**Solution from answers:**
This solution is working:

```
//Shared code. When the argument length is two, it is coming from the context
// menu, while a single argument is coming from the browser action.
function fctContext() {
   var tab = arguments.length == 2 ? arguments[1] : arguments[0];
   // Do whatever you want with the tab.
}

// Browser Action
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(fctContext);

// Context Menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
   title: myTitle,
   contexts: ['page'],
   onclick: fctContext
});
```

**Solution after testing some other things:**

```
function fctStart() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){ 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'abc.js'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'xxx.js'});
  }); 
}
```

In this case, `fctStart()` is working from any point without having to pass the tab.

Comment: I would recommend separating out the effect from the trigger.

E.g. create a `function do_something(){}` and stick that in the extension so that the behavior is a complete different function that is simply informed & triggered by the click.  Then you can re-use that `do_something();` function where-ever you need it instead of tying it to a chrome event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment/idea. This is something I already have tried. The problem is, that I don't know exactly how to get the correct "tab", which is the parameter of my current function within the addListener, outside the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`

Comment: I've merged your accounts. You can now comment on answers, edit your question or accept the answer that helped you :) Thanks for registering. Unfortunately, I could not merge the answer you left citing so many people, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the merge of the accounts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that arguments are optional in JavaScript. Each function has an associated `arguments` object. That arguments acts as an array. In your case, one of them requires that while the other doesn't. Having N arguments is the same in one function (Browser Action) than having M arguments in the other (Context Menu), the only difference between these two arguments is the `arguments.callee` which provides a way to reference the actual code within the function itself. You don't have to worry about that if you want something basic.

Your `fctContext` could be the share-able code between your browserAction click and your context menu. I did something similar in the Reload All Tabs extension.

Search for `this.reload` in https://github.com/mohamedmansour/reload-all-tabs-extension/blob/master/js/reload_controller.js, you will notice that `this.reload` is being used for the Context Menu and the Browser Action. You just share the code.

**UPDATED with the arguments example baked in:**

In your case, you do the exact same thing.

```
// Shared code. When the argument length is two, it is coming from the context
// menu, while a single argument is coming from the browser action.
function fctContext() {
   var tab = arguments.length == 2 ? arguments[1] : arguments[0];
   // Do whatever you want with the tab.
}

// Browser Action
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(fctContext);

// Context Menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
   title: myTitle,
   contexts: ['page'],
   onclick: fctContext
});
```

The problem with the above approach is maintainability, if the API changes it might break. Personally, I would rather explicitly name the arguments. So the user doesn't have to do a lookup in the arguments array.

```
function fctContext(tab) {
   // Do whatever you want with the tab.
}

// Browser Action
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(fctContext);

// Context Menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
   title: myTitle,
   contexts: ['page'],
   onclick: function (detail, tab) { fctContext(tab) }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I understand the point with the optional parameters. The problem in my case (I think) is that, chrome.tabs.executeScript needs the correct tab.id. The executed script has to be executed in the content and when I execute it without tab.id it is executed in the background. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Np, yes I understand. In that case you can play with the arguments keyword as I explained in my post. I have updated the post to show you how. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

In your particular example you don't need to pass `tab.id` as it would default to the current page anyway:

```
function fctContext() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'abc.js'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'xxx.js'});
}
```

If you do need the tab then:

```
function fctContext(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'abc.js'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'xxx.js'});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(fctContext);

chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": myTitle, "contexts":["page"], "onclick": function(info, tab) {
    fctContext(tab);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this special case I needed the tab.id since the .js to execute with executeScript have to be executed in the content and the call is in the background.

Comment: Daniel, as serg stated, the ID defaults to the selected tab of the current window for `chrome.tabs.executeScript` So it will work as well :)