# How does an auto refresh page extension works and how to recreate one with code?

Tags: javascript, automation, page-refresh

I'm looking for a way to recreate the functionality of a refreshing page extension on a browser (e.g. Auto refresh plus in Chrome) by using javascript. The problem is that I have no ideia how to achieve that.
I must find a way to refresh the page every second or so, click on a link that appears on the page from time to time, add a sound effect for when it appears and send an e-mail notification every time it appears.

I'm trying to use a simple javascript snippet to run in the console in order to refresh the page:

```
win1 = window.open("https://www.myUrl.com/");
timer1 = setInterval(function(){win1.location.href="https://www.myUrl.com/"}, 1500);
```

However, this implies running code from tab A on tab B which I found very challenging.
The code can't run on tab A alone because at the time it refreshes the page, it gets erased from the console.
I know it would have been so much easier to use an extension, but the platform I work for does not allowed any extensions.
I have basic HTML and javascript knowledge, but I find this would be a good project to learn more.
Also, if the solution involves other languages, I just need a direction to know where to look for and start this project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background Scripts vs Content Scripts in Chrome Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971869/background-scripts-vs-content-scripts-in-chrome-extensions)